# How can I make a waypoint only be "active" when in a post with JQuery Waypoints?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

This may be a bit hard to explain, so bear with me.

I have a large list of posts. I have a system in place with Waypoints where once you pass the title it slides to the right and becomes fixed, to show "You are now reading Lorum Ipsum".

Each title only has a class, not an ID, and since it is not a static webpage, I have to code using that class. I have accomplished this by using `$('.title').each(function(){...` and using the `this` keyword to reference each title.

My problem arises when I try to make the title disappear when the end of the post is reached, and another post is below it. I need the title to fade out when `.post-footer` is reached.

I thought of a way to make a "fake" unique ID for each title, since the title's parent (`.post`) has an ID generated by the CMS. I can make this "fake" ID by using `$(this.element).parent('.post').attr('id')` and adding `> .title` to it, and I thought there might be a way to use this ID in the solution to the problem. I messed around with it, but I couldn't get anything working.

Here's what I've got so far in terms of my title fixing:

```
$('.title').each(function() {
    //creating the waypoint
  $(this).waypoint(function(direction) {
      //testing fake ID
      //var titleID = $(this.element).parent('.post').attr('id') + ' > .title';
      //console.log(titleID);
      //if below waypoint, do animation
      if (direction === "down"){
          //fix the title
          $(this.element).addClass('titleFixed');
          //slide right
          $(this.element).animate({left:'10%'},250,function(){
              //slide title decoration right
              $(this).next().animate({left:'0'},50);
          });
          //if above waypoint, undo animation
      }else{
          //unfix the title
          $(this.element).removeClass('titleFixed');
          //animate left
          $(this.element).animate({left:'-3.5%'},240,function(){
              //animate title direction left
            $(this).next().animate({left:'-3.5%'},150);
          });
      }
  });
});
```

**TL;DR: How can I make the title of a post be fixed while it is in the post, disappear once the post is left, and then be replaced by the next post's title once in the next post? (and so on and so forth)**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: So I thought of a possible way to do it, it's kind of odd and I'm not entirely sure how to implement it, but what if I could make a system with objects or arrays to "store" each title's fake ID as it is passed? Then it could have a boolean attached to each ID, whether it is "above" it, or "below" it. Then when the last one is below, and any values below that are above, then I could make the title "active". Just a thought. I'll mess around with it some more later, can't get anything working right now.